# WSO2 APIM gives HTTP Status code 429 - Too Many Request

Tags: wso2-api-manager, http-status-code-429

I am running WSO2 APIM 2.1.0 , I am setting Tier Availability to Unlimited . Still getting 429 too many request error while doing load testing.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes as per given in [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Setting+Maximum+Backend+Throughput+Limits).
If you have custom throttling policies, it has some issues with WSO2-2.1.0. Better to get upgraded to wso2-2.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for this kind of issue.

1. Are you trying throttling scenario on unauthenticated API? When you are going to add a new Subscription level throttling tier in the admin portal, you could see the existing list of subscription tiers in the Subscription Tier List. In this list, you will find a tier named Unauthenticated which has a request quota of 500. This is a subscription tier that automatically applied when the authentication type of your resources is 'None'. That is used when you can invoke APIs without tokens. And this tier is not visible in the Throttling tier list of the application.
2. Please check the Traffic Manager node connectivity.
3. Check whether any other throttling tier like application, API, resource level are published with the API.
4. Check the unit time while you are getting the throttled out response. Invoke the API after unit time getting passed. If the unit time is a larger value, then you should restart the server and try again.
5. Check the throttling configurations in the gateway, traffic manager, and the publisher.